# Using XLA in TensorFlow libdevice.10.bc InternalEr

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

When I run this line of code:

```
tf.config.optimizer.set_jit(True)
```

To enable `XLA in TensorFlow 2.1`, I get the follow error:

```
InternalError:  libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
     [[{{node cluster_1_1/xla_compile}}]]
```

I've looked at this post here: https://github.com/google/jax/issues/989

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this via `Anaconda` and using `os.environ['XLA_FLAGS']` instead of having to run the `symlink command` beforehand.

For instance, I've tried:

```
os.environ['XLA_FLAGS'] = "--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/anaconda_path/envs/env/lib/libdevice.10.bc"
```

But I still get the same error. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04, TensorFlow 2.1, and Python 3.7.7`.

Comment: Found an answer to this? I'm trying to speed up my training from what I read here https://towardsdatascience.com/accelerate-your-training-and-inference-running-on-tensorflow-896aa963aa70 but that line seems to break everything

Comment: I'm on a windows environment by the way

Comment: Would also like to know if you ever found a fix as I'm in a similar situation

Comment: I succumb to this bug when using tf2.10 in pipy version. So I finally have to compile it from source. My env is `win11`, `cuda11.7.1`, `cudnn 8.5`.  But I still wonder if there is a convenient solution, not requiring recompiling.

Comment: I find a way that "set env" instead of "copy file" to deal with this bug if one is using PowerShell on windows. seed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73870568/17357963).