# TensorFlow libdevice not found. Why is it not found in the searched path?

Tags: python, tensorflow, configuration

Win 10 64-bit 21H1; TF2.5, CUDA 11 installed in environment (Python 3.9.5 Xeus)

I am not the only one seeing this error; see also (unanswered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289133/tensorflow-driver-issue-internal-libdevice-not-found-at-libdevice-10-bc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670495/using-xla-in-tensorflow-libdevice-10-bc-internaler).
The issue is obscure and the proposed resolutions are unclear/don't seem to work (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189268/how-to-let-tensorflow-xla-know-the-cuda-path))

**Issue** Using the TF Linear_Mixed_Effects_Models.ipynb example (download from TensorFlow github [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/tree/main/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks)) execution reaches the point of performing the "warm up stage" then throws the error:

```
InternalError: libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc [Op:__inference_one_e_step_2806]
```

The console contains this output showing that it finds the GPU but XLA initialisation fails to find the - existing! - libdevice in the specified paths

```
2021-08-01 22:04:36.691300: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9623 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2021-08-01 22:04:37.080007: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:348] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
2021-08-01 22:04:54.122528: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:169] XLA service 0x1d724940130 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-08-01 22:04:54.127766: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:177]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
2021-08-01 22:04:54.215072: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/random_ops.cc:241] Warning: Using tf.random.uniform with XLA compilation will ignore seeds; consider using tf.random.stateless_uniform instead if reproducible behavior is desired.
2021-08-01 22:04:55.506464: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:73] Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice. This may result in compilation or runtime failures, if the program we try to run uses routines from libdevice.
2021-08-01 22:04:55.512876: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:74] Searched for CUDA in the following directories:
2021-08-01 22:04:55.517387: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:77]   C:/Users/Julian/anaconda3/envs/TF250_PY395_xeus/Library/bin
2021-08-01 22:04:55.520773: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:77]   C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.2
2021-08-01 22:04:55.524125: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:77]   .
2021-08-01 22:04:55.526349: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:79] You can choose the search directory by setting xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir in HloModule's DebugOptions.  For most apps, setting the environment variable XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/path/to/cuda will work.
```

Now the interesting thing is that the paths searched includes "C:/Users/Julian/anaconda3/envs/TF250_PY395_xeus/Library/bin"

the content of that folder includes all the (successfully loaded at TF startup) DLLs, including cudart64_110.dll, dudnn64_8.dll... and of course **libdevice.10.bc**

**Question** Since TF says it is searching this location for this file and the file exists there, what is wrong and how do I fix it?

(NB `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.2` does not exist... CUDA is intalled in the environment; this path must be a best guess for an OS installation)

Info: I am setting the path by

```
aPath = '--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=C:/Users/Julian/anaconda3/envs/TF250_PY395_xeus/Library/bin'
print(aPath)
os.environ['XLA_FLAGS'] = aPath
```

but I have also set an OS environment variable XLA_FLAGS to the same string value... I don't know which one is actually working yet, but the fact that the console output says it searched the intended path is good enough

Comment: Your eventual solution at https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/libdevice-not-found-why-is-it-not-found-in-the-searched-path/3419/10 solved the issue for me, thanks.

Comment: I had forgotten about that... glad it helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The diagnostic information is unclear and thus unhelpful; there is however a resolution

**The issue was resolved by providing the file (as a copy) at this path**

`C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\TF250_PY395_xeus\Library\bin\nvvm\libdevice\`

Note that `C:\Users\Julian\anaconda3\envs\TF250_PY395_xeus\Library\bin` was the path given to XLA_FLAGS, but it seems it is not looking for the libdevice *file* there it is looking for the \nvvm\libdevice\ *path* This means that I can't just set a different value in XLA_FLAGS to point to the actual location of the libdevice file because, to coin a phrase,  it's not (just) the *file* it's looking for.

The debug info earlier:

```
2021-08-05 08:38:52.889213: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:73] Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice. This may result in compilation or runtime failures, if the program we try to run uses routines from libdevice.
2021-08-05 08:38:52.896033: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:74] Searched for CUDA in the following directories:
2021-08-05 08:38:52.899128: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:77]   C:/Users/Julian/anaconda3/envs/TF250_PY395_xeus/Library/bin
2021-08-05 08:38:52.902510: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:77]   C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.2
2021-08-05 08:38:52.905815: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:77]   .
```

is incorrect insofar as there is no "CUDA" in the search path; and FWIW I think a different error should have been given for searching in `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.2` since there is no such folder (there's an old V10.0 folder there, but no OS install of CUDA 11)

Until/unless path handling is improved by TensorFlow such file structure manipulation is needed in every new (Anaconda) python environment.

Full thread in TensorFlow forum [here](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/libdevice-not-found-why-is-it-not-found-in-the-searched-path/3419/10)

Comment: For ubuntu https://stackoverflow.com/a/72145676/8609909

Answer (score 32):

The following worked for me. With error message:

```
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
```

Firstly I searched for `nvvm` directory and then verified that `libdevice` directory existed:

```
$ find / -type d -name nvvm 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/cuda/nvvm
$ cd /usr/lib/cuda/nvvm
/usr/lib/cuda/nvvm$ ls
libdevice
/usr/lib/cuda/nvvm$ cd libdevice
/usr/lib/cuda/nvvm/libdevice$ ls
libdevice.10.bc
```

Then I exported the environment variable:

```
export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/usr/lib/cuda
```

as shown by @Insectatorious above. This solved the error and I was able to run the code.

Comment: The above approach did not work for me when using a custom environment on a cluster. Probably tensorflow expects to locate nvvm folder in your custom environment. Somehow `conda install cudatoolkit` did not create nvvm folder. 
What worked for me is to `conda install -c nvidia cuda-nvcc` and then export the path of `cuda-nvcc` folder as done above.

Comment: I'm using Windows, so I had to add the path with quotes around:

`os.environ['XLA_FLAGS'] = '--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir="/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.2"'`

Answer (score 14):

**for Windows** user

**Step-1**

run (as administrator)

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit
```

you can specify the cudatoolkit version as per your installed cudaCNN /supported version
ex:conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=10.2.89

**Step-2**

go to the installed conada folder

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

**Step-3**

locate "**libdevice.10.bc**" ,copy the file

**Step-4**

create a folder named "**nvvm**" inside bin

create another folder named "**libdevice**" inside nvvm

paste the "**libdevice.10.bc**" file inside "libdevice"

**Step-5**

go to environmental variables

System variables >New

variable name:

> XLA_FLAGS

variable value:

> --xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

(edit above as per your directory)

**Step-6**
restart the cmd/virtual env

Comment: This would be more useful if the reasons behind the specific steps were provided - understanding is reusable :)

Comment: Follow this thread for more information. :https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/libdevice-not-found-why-is-it-not-found-in-the-searched-path/3419/10

Comment: SE answers should seek to be self-contained. And you referred me to the thread that *I* started. My comments boil down to: what are you adding to the answer I gave previously and why does it matter? What is distinctive about your contribution? Answering that will help others decide which answer is most relevant to their needs.

Comment: yep yep . the program uses the XLA_FLAGS(env variable) to get the path of CUDA_DIR ,but its unable to access  the .bc file outside the Anaconda env So i installed cuda in anaconda the i created /nvvm/libdevice ,as in the program it says $CUDA_DIR/nvvm/libdevice and placed the file there . and why its unable to access outside of anaconda i tried to find which module is extracting the file ,but can't find it so, that's all the expiation .

Answer (score 5):

For those using windows and PowerShell, assuming cuda is in `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7`

The environment can be set as:

```
$env:XLA_FLAGS="--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir='C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7'"
```

Here `"''"`, i.e. nested quotes, is required!

I think this may be the lightest way to deal with this XLA bug.

Comment: Just in case someone wishes to manually enter the system variable in Windows 10. Here is how:
Go to Type here to search box. 
Search for Environment variables -> System Variables -> New -> 

Variable name put XLA_FLAGS

Variable value put 
"--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir='C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.2'" 

without the double quotation marks on the outside. 
(Assuming your CUDA version is 12.2).

Answer (score 5):

For those using miniconda just copy the file libdevice.10.bc into the root folder of python application or notebook.

It works here using  python=3.9, cudatoolkit=11.2, cudnn=8.1.0, and tensorflow==2.9

Comment: On Linux, you may also set the `XLA_FLAGS` with the following command:
`export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=$CONDA_PREFIX`. It worked with python3.10 and cudatoolkit=11.2.

Answer (score 3):

i meet the same error with Tensorflow 2.11,CUDA 11.2, cuDNN 8.1.0. because i use `conda` build the env, so no nvvm directory and no need to export the environment variable and can't use the command `nvcc -V`, so many suggestions i searched are not suitable for my problem.
i solve the error by downgrade tensonflow to 2.10. Use `conda install tensorflow=2.10.0 cudatoolkit cudnn` to downgrade your tensorflow version and its dependencies.
reference:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/58681

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem on fresh install Ubuntu 24.04 with Nvidia RTX3090
I used instructions from this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
and I couldn't run model.fit because it gave me the error.
Then in attempt to resolve the issue I've installed this driver: NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.105.17.run but it didn't help.

I believe this actually solved the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit
```

Answer (score 2):

For linux users, with `tensorflow==2.8` add the following environment variable.

```
XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/usr/local/cuda-11.4
```

Comment: Are you installing CUDA toolkit in the base environment? The current tutorial asks to install within a tf environment, and I am still having this problem on Linux - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2

Answer (score 2):

In my case I noticed that there was an error regarding to Adam at the final line :

```
libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
         [[{{node Adam/StatefulPartitionedCall_88}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_10134]
```

I changed this line:
`from keras.optimizers import Adam`

to this:
`from keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam`

and it worked. It was suggested in this link:
https://github.com/keras-team/tf-keras/issues/62

There are some other suggestions for this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 using tensorflow in jupyter-lab.
I have done the following three things (not sure which one actually fixed it):

1. Copy `libdevice.10.bc` to working folder (where jupyter lab is started)
2. `export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/usr/lib/cuda/`
3. In python code (before training) `os.environ["XLA_FLAGS"] = "--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/usr/lib/cuda/"`

Comment: 1 + 2 or 3 seems to work. No need to do 2 and 3 at the same time.